# Xamarin development - Resource.Id issue, Resource.Id does not contain item

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am following a tutorial for my assignment - android development in visual studio.

I drag and drop a button to the UI as the following.  The XML file has a corresponding code for the button.

[image]

XML file
[image]

The button's id is `button1`.

And I tried to link a Toast function (`MyButton_Click`) to the button in the activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        Button myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        myButton.Click += MyButton_Click;
    }
```

However, VS reports a warning before I build the solution.
[image]

I searched the button1 property in `Resource.Designer.cs` the property is there.
[image]

After I build the solution, it becomes an error as the following:

[image]

I have clean the solution and rebuild it a few times, and it is not going away.  I am not sure if this is a VS bug or I missed anything.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I follow your step to create one android project and drag one button, I also have this warning, you don't need to worry about it, just run your project, I have no problem. If you still have this problem, try to clean obj and bin for your project, clean project, build again.

Comment: Yeah it is very strange. I reckon Visual Studio is buggy again.

Comment: I suggest you create new project to test again. If you still have this problem,  you can try to repair your visual studio.